# Fetch and display uncompressed pixel values in web browser

Tags: javascript, image, dom

Suppose I have get json data like this from an HTTP server:

```json
{
     "width":1234,
     "height":356,
     "channels":"rgba",
     "sample_type":"uint8",
     "intensity_transfer_function":"sRGB",
     "pixels":"<encoded raw pixels>"
}
```

Here, it is assumed that pixels are not encoded using JPEG or PNG. Instead the data contains "displayable" pixels, where the string

- Consists of either pairs of hexadecimal digits (ff0000ff would mean a red pixel), or
- Is a base-64 representation of all pixel values

Is it possible to show the data in a web browser using JavaScript, or do the server have to send it as a PNG?

As a side note: The above sets `sample_type` to `uint8` and `intensity_transfer_function`. This can be represented by a PNG, so there would be no information loss there. However, I am also interesting in dealing with stuff that are outside the PNG spec, such as `sample_type` `float32` and  `intensity_transfer_function` set to `linear`, to not loose any information sent by the server.

Comment: @Phil: No: because my data is not a PNG. It is an array of uncompressed pixels, and its dimensions are in the json header.

Comment: Read this https://localcoder.org/uint8array-to-image-in-javascript